# Generate sequence of prime numbers up to Long.MaxValue, C#

Tags: c#, primes, sieve-of-eratosthenes

Implementing the sieve of eratosthenes on C# using array of boolenas with size of type long gives overflow exception, sure it is because array type in c# is limited to be max size of 32-bit integer. As I understand, it is because usually user cannot store bigger then 32 bit integer sized arrays in RAM. But we have boolean type, which is only 2-bit information, so required ram for such array supposed to be $2 * Long.MaxValue$. so the questions are following:

1) How to genereate sequence of primes up to Long.MaxValue?

2) Which data type is better to use to store such sequence?

3) Can we redefine our own array type with greater than 32-bit maximal size?

My try is here:

```
public bool[] MakeSieve(long max)
    {
        // Make an array indicating whether numbers are prime.
        bool[] is_prime = new bool[max + 1];
        for (int i = 2; i <= max; i++) is_prime[i] = true;

        // Cross out multiples.
        for (int i = 2; i <= max; i++)
        {
            // See if i is prime.
            if (is_prime[i])
            {
                // Knock out multiples of i.
                for (int j = i * 2; j <= max; j += i)
                    is_prime[j] = false;
            }
        }
        return is_prime;
    }
```

Sure, it throws Overflow Exception.

Comment: Array indices greater than int.MaxValue are not allowed, even if you have set things up so you can have arrays that *occupy* more than 2GB of space. However even if you could, it's unlikely that you would be able to find more than a tiny proportion of all the primes up to 2^63 using a sieve... It would take a long time to run.

Comment: @MatthewWatson Actually, generating of all primes up to Int64 was performed in 2010, using segmented sieve, see http://sweet.ua.pt/tos/software/prime_sieve.html ; Still, even we can't store such data in array, perhaps are there any other data types fit for this ?

Comment: According to that article, it took around 3 seconds to process 2^30 numbers near 2^64, so to process ALL the values will take a lot longer. (There are 2^34 times as many numbers still to process all the way up to 2^64, and even allowing for much faster PCs and the fact that it takes exponentially less time to process numbers further away from 2^64, that's still going to be a very long time.)

Comment: Putting it another way, there are approximately `400,000,000,000,000,000` primes up to 2^64. Assuming you could generate an incredible 10 billion of those per second, it would still take well over a year to generate all of them...